# Unable to run javascript in partial view called using ajax call MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this JavaScript code in a partial view that gets the Geo-location of a client.

```
<h1>Map</h1>
<style type="text/css">
    #map-canvas {
        height: 500px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{name:'maps',version:3,other_params:'sensor=false'}]}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">        
    function initialize() {

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4219985, -122.0839544);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: myLatlng
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Provider'
        });

    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

From another view I am making an Ajax call to load this partial view on an action-link click.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.provider-details').on('click', function (e) {

            $.get("/Provider/Map", function (response) {
                $('#map').html(response)
            });

            e.preventDefault();
        })
    });
</script>
```

I am able to call the partial view, I can see the text; however, the map is not loading. I can see the map if I load the view directly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

your initialize function is not triggering cause its probably attached to window not the body. just call it after the ajax call succeeds and you're good to go:

```
$(function () {
    $('.provider-details').on('click', function (e) {

        $.get("/Provider/Map", function (response) {
            $('#map').html(response);
            initialize();
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you Volkan for suggesting a solution. However, this doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: No. As I mentioned earlier, I can see the map when I call the partial view directly in browser. And my ajax call is able to render this view too; however, only text is visible!